# Struggling with basic implementation of ListView for Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I've recently began working through Android tutorials and, though not a tutorial in itself, I've started working from [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews) in an attempt to implement a simple `ListView`.

I've started with a New Android Application Project in a version of the Android SDK that I downloaded just last week, and have modified two files in a way that I believe to be in line with the above material, and [this page](http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90).

However, upon starting my application up on my HTC One, it immediately fails with the message `"Unfortunately, [my app] has stopped."` I've found a single line of code that I can comment out to make it not crash, but in doing so I'm avoiding initialising the `ListView` and so the result is an empty view.

As mentioned, I've only changed the contents of two files from the default for a New Android Application Project, but here they are in full:

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testproj.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/main_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.recipeorganiserforandroid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] myArray = new String[] {"Tomato", "Potato", "Carrot", "Mushroom", "Beef", "Cheese", "Lettuce", "Bread", "Milk", "Spinach", "Chicken", "Rice"};

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArray);

        myList.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

I note that the second example page I linked to above used a different constructor for `ArrayAdapter` but trying that doesn't give me more success. If I comment out the line `myList.setAdapter(adapter);` then my application runs successfully but, obviously, doesn't provide any content within my `ListView` view.

I've had a look for other examples online but all I've found have been considerably more complicated and I don't think throwing more ideas into the mix is going to make this any clearer in my mind. Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Show us the logcat please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using a `Fragment`, you should be initializing the data and setting the adapter in the `Frament` class. For that reason your app is crashing, when you call `myList.setAdapter(adapter)` from the Activity, `myList` is probably `Null` because you are trying to retrieve it from the Activity, and the `ListView` is in the `Fragment`.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        String[] myArray =
                new String[] {
                        "Tomato", "Potato", "Carrot", "Mushroom", "Beef", "Cheese", "Lettuce",
                        "Bread", "Milk", "Spinach", "Chicken", "Rice"
                };

        ListView myList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_main);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                         myArray);

        myList.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```